# MVC one to many relationship in model

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, model

So I'm new to MVC and I'm creating Model classes which have 1:N relationship with another classes, for example

```
public class Post {
    private int id;
    private String message;
    // setters and getters
}

public class Comment {
    private int id;
    private int postId;
    private String text;
    // setters and getters
}
```

My question would be, do MVC standards says I need to have a `List<Comment>` inside my `Post` class?

Answer (score 2):

The model, in your case `Post` has to bring everything the view needs to display, i.e a post should hold a collection of its comments.

The way you have designed it now you'll need two models and two views, one for the post and one for the comments to a post. Or at least two models and one view, but you still need to query both separately

Actually your design would only make sense if you have two views, one for the post and one for its comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will have one post with multiple comments for each view you should set it up so the Model contains the post and all of it's comments.  The view will then determine how to display the post.  That way you can have multiple views for the same model if you wanted to have different layouts.  Each view can decide to display the post differently but the model doesn't need to change.

A controller would handle any actions between the view and the model.  The view should not directly modify the model.  Instead, the view defines how the user can interact with the underlying data, passes that to the controller, which then modifies the model.  That way, if you had two views with the same model, they could act independently and still get the same updates.

I like to have all of my models extend this class.  It simply keeps me from having to write the code for listeners each time.

```
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

/**
 * AbstractModel - Base class for a Model in a MVC pattern. This class contains
 * an EventListenerList to allow for notification of a view that it's model has
 * changed.
 */
public abstract class AbstractModel {

private final EventListenerList observers = new EventListenerList();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
protected AbstractModel() {
}

/**
 * Add a ModelChangeListener
 * 
 * @param listener
 */
public void addModelChangedListener(final ModelChangedListener listener) {
    observers.add(ModelChangedListener.class, listener);
}

/**
 * Notifies listeners that the model has changed. Use the event property
 * name to determine what has changed
 * 
 * @param event
 */
protected void fireModelChangedEvent(final ModelChangedEvent event) {
    for (final ModelChangedListener l : observers
            .getListeners(ModelChangedListener.class)) {
        l.modelChanged(event);
    }
}

/**
 * Remove a ModelChangeListener
 * 
 * @param listener
 */
public void removeModelChangedListener(final ModelChangedListener listener) {
    observers.remove(ModelChangedListener.class, listener);
}
}


import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;

/**
 * ModelChangedEvent - An event used when a view's model has changed.
 *
 */
public class ModelChangedEvent extends PropertyChangeEvent {

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param source
 * @param propertyName
 * @param oldValue
 * @param newValue
 */
public ModelChangedEvent(final Object source, final String propertyName,
        final Object oldValue, final Object newValue) {
    super(source, propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
}
}

import java.util.EventListener;

/**
 * Interface for classes interested in ModelChangedEvents. Intended to be used
 * by view classes in a MVC pattern.
 */
public interface ModelChangedListener extends EventListener {

    /**
     * Notifies this Listener that the model has changed.
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    public void modelChanged(ModelChangedEvent event);
}
```